# PHP Find and replace certain string pattern

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have piece of html code in php $string . The problem is, I need to remove all "img" and "a href" tags from it. I guess I should use preg_replace function, but how should my patterns look like?

I would like to replace:

```
"<img some params and address>" with ""
```

and

```
"<a href="some random address with unknown length">my text</a>" with "my text"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) with Regular Expressions. Something like this:

```
$text = preg_replace("/<img (.*?)>/i", "", $text);
$text = preg_replace("/<a (.*?)>(.*?)</a>/i", "$2", $text);
```

Comment: This isn't a good idea. [The pony he comes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2370483)

Comment: @Machavity It doesn't matter since he only wants to replace it with something. He doesn't want to parse HTML to do something later with it.

Comment: What is the practical difference, though? You're still parsing it with regex, which doesn't work well with nested languages like HTML